# I want richfaces site, viewsource link and Hide link functionality look and feel?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I want the below look and feel functionality in jsf?

http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/componentControl.jsf#

If you go to the above url code,

When you click on **View Source** link , how it shows?
and in the same way, when you click on **hide** link, it hides the code.

I want that same look and feel in my project...

How is it be done? How to achieve it in jsf?

Comment: Hello Mat, can u help me in getting the above functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using RichFaces, you can use the    `<rich:effect>` tag component which uses [Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/). This is a js framework who enables to add effects in pages. In the example above, the effects used are [Effect.SlideDown](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/effect-slidedown/) and Effect.SlideUp (sorry for not placing the link here, but as a new user I can just post a max of two hyperlinks). If you are not using RichFaces, you can still add the js libraries to your web project and use them to add these great effects.